# equivalent MASM .const section in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, masm

What is the exact NASM equivalent of below MASM code?

```
; Simple lookup table (.const section data is read-only)
      .const
const_array dword 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
```

Comment: Consult the NASM manual, in particular sections [7.5](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.5) and [3.2.1](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `.const` MASM directive denotes a *read-only* segment, you have to use the NASM equivalent `section .rdata`<sup>1</sup> which creates a segment/section which is readable, but not writeable.

You can put DWORDs anywhere by using the `DD` directive; see [Section 3.2.1](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.1) of the manual.

The final result could look like this:

```
section .rdata
  const_array:   dd 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
```

A `:` after label names is always recommended in NASM.

When the first token on the line isn't recognized as an instruction mnemonic NASM will assume it's a label.  But it's a good habit to always use `:` to make that unambiguous.

---

Footnote 1:

Windows uses `.rdata`.  Some other OSes including Linux use `section .rodata`  for read-only non-executable data.

Comment: On Windows, `.rdata`.  On Linux (and I think *BSD), `.rodata`.  Not sure what section names MacOS uses.

Comment: Fun fact: you could use a `%rep` / `%endrep` to calculate the Fibonacci sequence at assemble time, out to a given length.  Not that that would make a better example :P

Comment: @peter-cordes I'm following [this](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-X86-Assembly-Language-Programming/dp/1484240626) book to get familiar with x86-64 assembly and SIMD instructions, but this book follows Windows & MASM environment so I have to convert the example exercise to NASM & Linux environment to execute them.

Comment: @Vencat: ok.  Note that the standard calling convention uses different registers on Linux (the x86-64 System V ABI) than on Windows.  So you'll have to know how to translate C library calls like `printf`, and of course WinAPI calls won't exist unless you build Windows executables and run them under Wine.  So any system calls like VirtualProtect will have to get replaced with POSIX equivalents like `mprotect`.